# SQL-PHP datetime

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm integrating an RSS feed unto my website and i need to create a table:

```
CREATE TABLE `stories` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `when` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
)
```

i know how to insert id, title, description but i do not know how to insert the time of the post (user submits  them). I used the script given [here](http://www.script-tutorials.com/how-to-easily-make-your-own-rss-feed/).

```
mysql_query("insert into stories (title,description) VALUES ('$_POST[title]','$_POST[description]') ");
```

Comment: Your current script is vulernable to SQL Injection
http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Answer (score 4):

For when use the date function:

```
date('Y-m-d h:i:s')
```

By default the date function uses the current date/time if you don't supply one as the second argument.